# Getting the original link on Wikipedia?

Tags: hyperlink, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have some links to wikipedia articles, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_jobs when you visit that link, you will see right under the article's title: `(Redirected from Steve jobs)` If you follow that link you will eventually reach a page with the same URL except that Steve_jobs has a capital J for jobs. So it would look like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs

Is there a way I can retrieve the latter link using the first one?

Comment: Yes. Do you want to know it from the page, or do you want to use the API?

Comment: I want to automate the process as i have quite a few links.. so maybe using the API or any other way (like crawling the page for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out where does a certain title redirect to by API query like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Steve%20jobs&redirects

If you want the result in XML, add `&format=xml` to the URL, or `&format=json` for JSON.

Comment: I also found that this: `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=steve%20jobs&redirects&prop=info&inprop=url|protection|talkid&format=json` can get the full link

Comment: Yes, but you don't need `protection` or `talkid` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [query api](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery). With http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Steve+jobs|steve+jobs|steve+Jobs|Steve+Jobs&redirects you will get your titles normalized and redirected. See the [api documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page) for further options, especially the [formats](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aData_formats).